# How to optimize a subset of JavaScript files created as RequireJS modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I have single-page web application that uses RequireJS to organize and structure JavaScript code. **Inside the app, I have some JS files that I want to optimize using r.js because they belong to an API that will be consumed by my customers. So, I just want to optimize those files and keep the rest of the code as it is now.**

This is my application structure:

- app

  - main.js
  - many other files and folders
- scripts

  - myAPI

    - app.js
    - many other files and folders
  - require.js
  - jquery.js
  - build.js
- index.htm

All the JavaScript code is located under the *app* and *scripts* folders. As I mentioned before, all those files are defined as RequireJS modules. This is how the main.js looks now:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        base: 'myAPI/base',
        proxy: 'myAPI/proxyObject',
        localization: 'myAPI/localization',
        app: '../app',
    }

});
require(['myAPI/app'],
    function (app) {
        //app.init....
    }
);
```

As you can see, in the *paths* configuration I'm defining some aliases that point to *myAPI* (the folder I want to optimize).

This is how I reference RequireJS from the index.htm file:

```
<script data-main="app/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

This is the build file I created for r.js (scripts/build.js):

```
({
   baseUrl: '.',
   out: 'build/myAPI.js',

   name: 'myAPI/app',
   include: ['some modules'],
   excludeShallow: ['some modules defined in the app folder'],

   mainConfigFile: '../app/main.js',
   optimize: 'uglify2',
   optimizeCss: 'none'
})
```

**The optimized file is generated, but I have some challenges trying to use it**:

1. How do I reference that file from the app?
2. The dependencies to *myAPI* modules are broken now. RequireJS doesn't find the modules defined in *myAPI*.
3. What can I do to keep the aliases defined in require.config.paths working?

Could you please help me with some suggestions or feedback for this situation?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research, I could solve my problem. I based my solution in this Github project created by James Burke: https://github.com/requirejs/example-libglobal.

First, I had to remove all the dependencies to *myAPI* individual modules, and create an object that centralizes the access to any internal dependency. Then, I created a r.js script to generate a single file for myAPI. That file is the one that will consumed by the other JS files. That single file can be referenced as a global object or as an AMD module, as James Burke shows in the Github project.

The aliases defined in require.config.paths were no longer necessary.